# ZoomIn animation from relative to fixed position

Tags: html, css, sass, css-animations

I have sample code on [codepen here](https://codepen.io/bojanv55/pen/LYNbwde)

```css
.liel{
  position: relative;
}

.parent{
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  z-index:100;
}

.green{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:green;
}

@keyframes zoomIn {
  0%{
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.zoom{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  position: fixed;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: zoomIn 5s;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="liel">
      <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="zoom"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

There are 2 rectangles - one red and one green.
Green can be anywhere on the screen.

What I'm trying to create is zoom-in animation from position of green rectangle to the final position of red rectangle. I'm trying somehow to get starting position relative to green rectangle, but cannot do it since `.parent` element is also fixed in position.

Currently red element has zoom-in effect but initial position is `left:0 top:0` which is position of `.parent` and not `.green`.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you. (Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918319/how-to-animate-to-position-fixed) other stackoverflow answer)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout( function(){
    $('.green').addClass('fixed');
},1000);
    $('.green').css('position','fixed');
});
```

```css
.liel{
  position: relative;
}

.parent{
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  z-index:100;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.green {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:green;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

  

.zoom{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  position: fixed;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: zoomIn 5s;
}

.fixed {
  animation: zoomIn 5s;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}

@keyframes zoomIn {
  0%{
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    opacity: 0;
 
  }
  100%{
    opacity: .5;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="liel">
      <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="zoom"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this one use javascript (jquery) as a part of solution. I was looking for pure css (if that is possible at all...)

Comment: also, I do not need green one to move. Just red one but starting from green coordinates.